# Flask routing using wsgi not working

Tags: python, apache, flask

I have a simple flask app I'm working on (my website), but for whatever reason routing doesn't work. It will only present '/' - nothing else. However, when I use the embedded debug server, it all routes fine to where it needs to go.

I've followed [this](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) tutorial to the letter. Any help is greatly appreciated.

View.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
   return render_template("index.html", title='Site Title')

@app.route('/software/')
def software():
   return "LALALA"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

run.wsgi

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/www/flaskweb')

from web import web as application
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it will only present '/'"? What happens if you type '/software/' in the address bar?

Comment: Do you use apache + mod_wsgi? What's is your 'run.wsgi' used for?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. It was an issue in my package names. Thanks!!